# Unexpected pixel value change after setRGB and imageIO.write

Tags: java, rgb, pixel

I need to write gray image from value that i generate. This is a piece of code i use, but i make it simple.

```
BufferedImage test = new BufferedImage(1,1,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
int rgb =(3 & 0xff) << 16 | (3 & 0xff) << 8 | (3 & 0xff);
test.setRGB(0, 0, rgb);
ImageIO.write(test, "png", new File("/home/harris/cipher.png"));
```

This code will generate image with one pixel. The pixel value should be 3, but i got 0 instead. what's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things going on here.  First, you are attempting to set a 3 byte color for a 1 byte pixel.  The color depth of the pixel is indicated by TYPE_BYTE_GRAY.  If you use TYPE_INT_RGB instead, the code will work as written, but will not yield a gray scale image.

If you really do want a gray scale image, then you should keep TYPE_BYTE_GRAY.  However, you cannot manipulate the pixels as RGB, so you can extract the WriteableRaster and manipulate that as follows:

```
WritableRaster raster = test.getRaster();

int [] gray = new int[1];
gray[0] = 3;
raster.setPixel(0, 0, gray);
```

*When encoded as a PNG, this example actually yields a pixel value of 2.  Setting the value above to 4 yields pixel value of 3.  However, when encoding this to a BMP, the color was written as expected.  I am not a PNG expert, but maybe this is some sort of image optimization?*